# Reformat Code in android layout

Tags: android, android-studio

when i press Code -> Reformat Code
layout become this shape

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:id="@id/til_full_name"
      android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:errorEnabled="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_choose_picture"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1">

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText android:id="@id/et_full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/name" android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/full_name" android:inputType="textCapWords" />
```

But i need it like this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout 
      android:id="@id/til_full_name"
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      app:errorEnabled="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_choose_picture"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1">

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText 
        android:id="@id/et_full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/name" 
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/full_name" 
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />
```

i don't know what changed the default format  I tried to reset everything to default but i need some help with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with "Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Other -> Wrap Attributes" in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried     Ctrl + Alt + L, Revert if you face any problem

Comment: It is happening only in one layout or other layouts too.When you do the reformat.